# Most Efficient Method of Searching Neighbour Data for Nth Neighbour

Tags: python, performance, list, list-comprehension

**Question**
My program generates several sets of data that enable me to render a network of vertices with their connections on a tkinter canvas. I need to be able to find the Nth neighbours of each vertex in the network. 
My code already identifies the connections of each vertex to their immediate neighbours, meaning the first set of neighbours are easily found using a list comprehension using the selected vertex as the value to search the data for. I effectively want to repeat this search for each neighbour, but in the most efficient method. The data (which I have already calculated) that is being searched through to achieve this is designated as `p_2` in the code below, and is of the form: (Origin Coordinate, Neighbour Coordinate), and `Coordinates_xyz` is a list of the unique vertices of the network. The code below demonstrates how I am currently identifying only the first neighbours. 
Again, *I already have all the neighbour data*, I simply need the best method to search through this data to find connections to each vertex.

**Clarity:**
Example of what I'm trying to do:
One type of data my program generates represents a network of vertices in a repeating square pattern. Each vertex (away from the edges) has 4 neighbours, and each neighbour then has 4 neighbours (although one neighbour of these neighbours is the previous vertex so is discounted) and so on.
If I were to choose vertex 20 with coordinates `(x20, y20, z20)` and search for neighbours in p_2 it may return (for example):
(Origin), (Neighbour)
`(x20, y20, z20), (x21, y21, z21)`
 `(x23, y23, z23), (x20, y20, z20)`
 `(x26, y26, z23), (x20, y20, z20)`
`(x20, y20, z20), (x30, y30, z30)`
I can then clearly see that vertex 21, 23, 26 and 30 are the neighbouring points in the network to vertex 20. However, I then need to repeat the search process for 21, 23, 26 and 30 respectively to find 2nd nearest neighbours. For N nearest neighbours, I must then find a way to make an efficient (as possible) method for repeating this search for every neighbour and proceed outwards from vertex 20, while keeping track of the order of the neighbour. Again, I'm aware this will be taxing for large N, but it will generally not operate at N>4.
The code below solves my problem for N = 1.

```
matching_1_NN_list=[]
matching_1_NN_list[:]=[]    
for vertex in xrange(len(Coordinates_xyz)):
    #Target vertex Coordinates_xyz[vertex] 
    matching_1_NN = [x for x in p_2 if Coordinates_xyz[vertex] in x]
    matching_1_NN_Component_0=column(matching_1_NN, 0)
    matching_1_NN_Component_1=column(matching_1_NN, 1)
    for x in matching_1_NN_Component_0:
        if x == Coordinates_xyz_final[vertex]:
            pass
        else:
            x=x, vertex, 1 #coordinates, vertex number, order (1 = first neighbour)
            matching_1_NN_list.append(x)


    for x in matching_1_NN_Component_1:
        if x == Coordinates_xyz_final[vertex]:
            pass
        else:
            x=x, vertex, 1
            matching_1_NN_list.append(x)
    matching_1_NN_list=set(list(matching_1_NN_list)) #Removes Duplicates
```

Comment: What do you mean by "up to 2nd nearest neighbours."? It's either "up to 2 nearest neighbours" or "2nd nearest neighbour". The same problem is with the notion "Nth neighbours" you're using - it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Having trouble understanding. Are you talking about the nearest spatial neighbours? If so where in your code are you computing distances?

Comment: If you do mean the nearest spatial neighbours and this isn't a learning exercise, use http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html

Comment: Apologies, when I say 'up to 2nd nearest neighbours', I simply mean that I wish to find and include all first and second neighbours. Again, I apologise for any confusion, and will update the question for clarity. I simply wished to avoid any responses that only returned 2nd NN.

Comment: But what are "all first and second neighbours"? There is only one first nearest neighbour and only one second nearest neighbour (moving aside degenerate cases).

Comment: My data represents a network of vertices in repeating square (or cubic) patterns. Taking the square pattern, each vertex has four neighbours, those four being my 1st NNs, each of these neighbours then has 4 neighbours, but 1 of these neighbours for each vertex is a duplicate, so there are 12 2nd NNs and so on. I'm looking to loop this process.

Comment: @MarkyD43 It is helpful if you are able to post code that is as complete as possible and as minimal as possible. Complete meaning: It would be best if we could directly run the code you've provided and see the problem for ourselves. As it is, we can only guess what the rest of your program is doing and where the problems may originate. Minimal meaning: Try to present your code without any irrelevant parts - try and isolate the problem before you show it to us. Cut out some function calls and replace with dummy values, etc. See: sscce.org You will get much better answers if you can do this!

Comment: Basically, it's still (to me) unclear what you want. So if you provide input, your existing (minimal, etc) method, and the results, we can better see what's going on

Comment: @Mr E, I can supply the structure/example of the data being fed into the above code if you like? Aside from that there is not much more to this part of the program that is relevant. As I say, I have a list of data (p_2 in the above code) that consists of each vertex's immediate neighbours, and so physically calculating which vertex neighbours which other vertex is not necessary. I will attempt to improve my question to better reflect this.

Comment: @MarkyD43 All right, so this is indeed a degenerate case of NN problem, where there is more than one nearest neighbour, strictly speaking. But the term "nearest neighbour" you're using is quite well established and usually means a different problem, hence the confusion. In your case it seems like you're dealing with neighbourhoods in a graph. Probably it would be more clear if you reworded the question using the terminology from the graph theory.

Comment: @BartoszKP, I apologise for the confusion. I didn't realise the nearest neighbour had such a specific meaning, I merely intended it to characterise that I'm looking for the nearest neighbours to a point in a network. I've updated my question to hopefully clarify my issue further. As I say, I've already solved the issue of finding the neighbours of each vertex, I'm simply trying to come up with a method to find the neighbour's neighbour and so on.

Comment: @MarkyD43 yes that would be great

Comment: It seems that what you need is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region_growing). Adjusting this to more than 2 dimensions seems trivial.

Comment: @Mr E I've updated my question to better show my data structure and my goal. I will try and get hold of a small set of sample data to show. Is that useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears a large part in optimizing this is improving the way you search for neighbours. In your current approach you loop over the whole list of pairs and do loads of membership checking for *each time* you need to find the neighbours of a vertex. Much better would be to do this step only once, and lookup the result in a dictionary. For example if you have the following vertices:

```
 7 |  E
 6 |
 5 |
 4 |  D
 3 |
 2 |     B  C
 1 |  A
 0 +----------
   0  1  2  3
```

With the following list of nearest neighbours:

```
p_2 = [('A', 'B'),
       ('B', 'C'),
       ('C', 'B'),
       ('D', 'B'),
       ('E', 'D')]
```

You could do e.g.:

```
from collections import defaultdict

p_2_dict = defaultdict(set)
for a, b in p_2:
    p_2_dict[a].add(b)
    p_2_dict[b].add(a)

def find_neigbours(start_vertex, levels):
    found = []
    from_vertices = [start_vertex]
    for i in range(1, levels+1):
        new_from_vertices = []
        for vertex in from_vertices:
            for neighbour in p_2_dict[vertex]:
                new_from_vertices.append(neighbour)
                found.append( (neighbour, i) )
        from_vertices = new_from_vertices
    return found
```

This however finds a lot of duplicates. Like you did in your example code you can use sets to store only unique values. Also if you encounter the start vertex you can skip it.

```
def find_neigbours(start_vertex, levels):
    found = set()
    from_vertices = [start_vertex]
    for i in range(1, levels+1):
        new_from_vertices = set()
        for vertex in from_vertices:
            for neighbour in p_2_dict[vertex]:
                if neighbour == start_vertex:
                    continue
                new_from_vertices.add(neighbour)
                found.add( (neighbour, i) )
        from_vertices = new_from_vertices
    return found
```

Still, this stores duplicate vertices if the "order of neighbour being" it is associated with is different than what is already stored. What would you like to do with those? Only store the order of when you first encountered a particular vertex?

Output:

```
In [49]: find_neigbours('A', 1)
Out[49]: set([('B', 1)])

In [50]: find_neigbours('A', 2)
Out[50]: set([('B', 1), ('D', 2), ('C', 2)])

# 'B' encountered with different order:
In [51]: find_neigbours('A', 3)
Out[51]: set([('B', 1), ('D', 2), ('B', 3), ('E', 3), ('C', 2)])
```

Comment: This is dead on, I'm just going to adapt it to my code, but thank you so much!